# Fitting an image inside an ImageView after rotation

Tags: android, runnable

I have an ImageView that I am rotating and I would like it to re-scale itself after the rotation is finished. (I would prefer a seamless animated rotation that scales down as it is rotating, but that is another topic.) I have a feeling that I need to make a runnable to achieve this, but I can't get it to work right. The image keeps the same size as before the rotation.

```
private void rotate() {
    imageView.animate().rotationBy(90).setDuration(100).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
    imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fitImageView();
        }
    });
}


private void fitImageView() {

    float imageWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    float imageHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    imageView.invalidate();

}
```

fitImageView() works fine to fit the image when it is first initialized, and I have confirmed from the log that fitImageView() is being called sometime during rotate().

Comment: your fitimageview() is working fine .but it is called before complete animation right?

Comment: I think so. It is hard to tell if it is being called before the animation from the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, I used the following code which uses an animation and an animation listener to call the method after the animation is complete. I still need to figure out how to resize the image once it is in the method since the getheight and getwidth are still the same values as before the rotation, but at least the method is being called after the rotation finishes.

```
imageView.animate().rotationBy(90).setDuration(2000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            fitImageView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).start();
```